# Can I get the backup of my aws instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, backup-restoration

Does aws store autoback up of my server?

Can I get get backup of my system before or restore my instance to last week or 2-3 days back state?

I my aws server got hacked and no data available in database. So If I can restore it then it will be great help for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you made a snapshot of your instance, you can create new volume from that snapshot, detach the current volume from your instance and attached the one restored from a snapshot.

There are also plenty of backup tools, which could serve the purpose.

It is a good practice to backup your instances, data etc etc, if you haven't done so, you will not be able to recover your instance, or the information you've stored on your volumes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-best-practices.html

Comment: Hey Thanks Dimitar. I I dont have created the snapshot, is there any way to restore? Or can aws team help anyway here? Do they care if any random person removes data from their server

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your case is, but I guess it wasn't Amazon who got compromised - it was you/your server/your account. If you haven't made a backup, you won't be able to restore your data. Sorry.

https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/data-privacy-faq/

Comment: @user123 It's not their instance its your instance.  That's what you bought was time on their hardware